# How to pass fragile data e.g connection string from one controller to another

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Im new to asp.net core and I was trying to develop an online SQL database manager, that will work on any SQL database, after passing: ServerAddress, Login, Password and DatabaseType (my ConnectionInformation model).

Something like SSMS but online.

I want to pass my ConnectionInformation model from Login controller to Database controller.

Redirecting to action uses query string which exposes all of my data.
TempData only accepts strings and converting my model to json isn't the most elegant way to solve this problem.

Login Controller:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILoginLogic _loginLogic;

    public LoginController(ILoginLogic loginLogic)
    {
        _loginLogic = loginLogic;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Index(ConnectionInformationViewModel connectionViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();

        ConnectionInformation connection = Mapper.Mapper.ConnectionInformationMapper(connectionViewModel);

        var connectionSuccess = _loginLogic.ConnectToDatabase(connection);

        if (connectionSuccess)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Database", connection);
        else
            return View(); // TODO: Return view with error or handle it in js
    }
}
```

Database Controller:

```
 public class DatabaseController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IDatabaseLogic _databaseLogic;

        public DatabaseController(IDatabaseLogic databaseLogic)
        {
            _databaseLogic = databaseLogic;
        }

        public IActionResult Index(ConnectionInformation connection)
        {
            var databases = _databaseLogic.GetDatabases(connection);
            return View(databases);
        }
    }
```

Prehaps my approach is totally wrong. My main goal is to check if I can connect to database, and if I can I want to perform query operations on that Database untill user logs out.

Comment: Perhaps you could simply write the login info to a file and let other part of your code use that file.

Comment: I that case i would rather use TempData. I was wondering if there is better way to do it, or perhaps my approach is totally wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, simply, you have to persist the information some way. In that regard, there's a number of options. You could persist it in local storage on the client and actually pass it back with each further request. That works better for SPA-style apps, where you're pretty much doing everything via AJAX, though. Another technically client-side storage mechanism would be setting a session cookie with the posted connection information. Here I'm talking about explicitly setting and reading from a cookie with a "session" lifetime, not using sessions.

Or you can can actually use a true session, i.e. `Session`. `TempData` is basically just `Session` anyways, but here it would be inappropriate as you'd then need to ensure that the `TempData` is kept every time it's accessed or it won't survive the next request. If you're doing that, then you might as well just use `Session` and not have to worry about it.

Serialization is pretty much required no matter what you do. There's no way to persist an actual C# object instance, so you're either going to have to write it to a relational store like a database or serialize it to JSON.

One alternate solution, which avoids having to persist the actual connection information is to basically create your own connection pool. This will require a singleton-scoped class with a `ConcurrentDictionary` ivar and likely the use of `SemaphoreSlim` to lock during reads and writes of that dictionary so that you don't create and orphan connections. Then, you'd just need to assign the key to their particular connection in the dictionary client somehow, such as via `Session` or a cookie. This is actually a little more secure as well, as you're not persisting the database connection info past the initial post, but you might end up exhausting the available server connections if there's too many simultaneous users. Of course, that could potentially be an issue regardless. You'll also need some policy for eviction of connections. It's not the easiest setup.

Personally, I'd just stick with using `Session` on this one. It's secure enough, as long as you take the standard session hijacking prevention measures, and it's simple to implement. If you are building a SPA-style app, then I'd stick with local storage, as that's going to be imminently better keeping the info client-side to begin with, but it requires a bit more plumbing that way.